# How to keep the checkbox checked, even after other checkboxes checked using angular2

Tags: angular

i have list of users and it gives checked for already shared user, now if i check on any one of the checkbox then the already checked one gets unchecked.
please anyone help me to sort this issue.

HTML:

```
<div *ngFor="let contact of userList">

              <input  type="checkbox" name="radio" (click)="selectCheckboxInvitee($event.target.checked, contact, false)"
                [(ngModel)]="contact.isChecked" [disabled]="contact.isDisabled" />
              <a>{{ contact.FirstName }} &nbsp;{{ contact.LastName }}</a>
            </div>
```

Ts:

```
 selectCheckboxInvitee(evt, contact, isMultiple) {
    if (evt) {

      if (!isMultiple) {
        this.userList.forEach(function (obj) {
          if (obj.Id === contact.Id) {
            obj.isChecked = true;
          }
          else {
            obj.isChecked = false;
          }
        });

      }

    }
  }

  getSharedIds(sPk) {
  //  this.dicom.getSharedIDs(sPk).subscribe(res => {
  //    if (res.Body) {
        const inviteeIds = this.res
          ? this.res.split(",")
          : [];
        this.userList.forEach(r => {
          r.isChecked = false;
        //  r.isDisabled = false;
          if (inviteeIds) {
            inviteeIds.forEach(i => {
              if (i == r.Id) {
                r.isChecked = true;
                r.isDisabled = true;
              }
            });
          }
        });
      }
```

DEMO:
[Please Find Demo here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-elghmx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Remove `(click)="selectCheckboxInvitee($event.target.checked, contact, false)"` unless you have a reason for that method it to be there?

Comment: ya it should be there so that from that itself i can make one checkbox to be checked at a time among unchecked boxes,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if object is not disabled

```
 selectCheckboxInvitee(evt, contact, isMultiple) {
    if (evt) {

      if (!isMultiple) {

        this.userList.forEach(function (obj) {
          if(!obj.isDisabled) {
            if (obj.Id === contact.Id) {
              obj.isChecked = true;
            }
            else {
              obj.isChecked = false;
            }
         }
      });
    }
  }   
}
```

stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zz3zg5

Alternatively you can use `filter`:

```
this.userList.filter(u => !u.isDisabled).forEach(function (obj) {
  if (obj.Id === contact.Id) {
    obj.isChecked = true;
  }
  else {
    obj.isChecked = false;
  }
});
```

Comment: I have one more, could u please help me, i want the checked ones to be enabled and display only the checked ones, when one name is unchecked rest must be chec ked and disabled

Comment: Im confused, could you elaborate it more?

Comment: ya, i have shown disabled ones na, which are already checked, now i need those fields to be shown and enabled and unchecked fields to be hidden,

Comment: No No, in stackblitz link i shared i have res = ["1580,1581,1432"]; So i want only these 3 names to be displayed with the checkboxes enabled. Now among 3 check boxes checked if i uncheck one of the checkbox, then rest 2 must b disabled. If i again check the checkbox which is unchecked then again 3 must be enabled with boxes checked.

Comment: so that, at a time only one checkbox can be unchecked.

Comment: @Bhrungarajni Ok so.. Something like this? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ije9ja

Comment: Hide unchecked names and display only the checked names and those displayed names should be enabled

Comment: Now if I uncheck anyone among the 3 checked ones , then unchecked one will be enable and 2 checked boxes will b disabled

Comment: @Bhrungarajni, well the basic is there, all you need to do is modify the HTML template for the hidden part.

Answer (score 0):

Well it behaves exactly the way you wrote the code. I can see that you have a method `selectCheckboxInvitee` that takes an argument called `isMultiple` in your binding.

Just change this in your html:

```
selectCheckboxInvitee($event.target.checked, contact, false)
```

to

```
selectCheckboxInvitee($event.target.checked, contact, true)
```

and it's going to let you select multiple checkboxes

Comment: Here the 3 checkboxes which are disabled must be checked, but in the unchecked boxes, one must b checked at a time